# Laravel models migrations Inheritance

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, migration

I have the next structure

> Table Employees (name, email, phone, direction)

The following tables extends from Employess

> Table Coach (typeCoach, profesion)
>
> Table Receptionist (idEmploye)

How can i Do models and migrations inheritance without repeating variables in migrations for example and login with different tables?

Comment: Migrations are only run once, seems kind of pointless to worry about inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You won't make any inheritance at the level of migrations because these are to create your database.
What you can do is, you repeat those fields and then you make your inheritance on your models...  I think it's the suitable solution, but it can be a more interesting way to do that.